# Не дает исправить ошибку "Минимальная длина правки 6 символов..."

Tags: обсуждение, поддержка, статус-так-задумано

**Здравствуйте!**

Увидел ошибку в данной теме - [**Клик**](https://rus.stackexchange.com/a/17309/185478)

Первый ответ:

> Дело, конечно, не в **Вроде**

Очевидно, что там должно быть "Дело, конечно, не в **Ворде**".
Но мне не дает система отредактировать данное сообщение(я нажимаю кнопку *править*), т.к. выдает ошибку `"Минимальная длина правки 6 символов; исправить ещё что-нибудь в сообщении?"`.
Я более ничего править там не хочу. Это показывает несовершенность данной проверки.

**Мой вопрос:** Хочется чтобы, то сообщение можно было отредактировать, не достигая этих 6 символов, но я подозреваю, что это "базовое" правило всей сети *stackexchange*, и отдельные его "подгруппы"(такие как "Русский язык *бета*") не могут это изменить, прав ли я? Возможно, это возможность есть у модераторов?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Здравствуйте!

Я внес предложенную вами правку, однако считаю нужным напомнить о том, что правки предназначены для внесения более или менее значительных изменений, которые могут существенно повлиять на восприятие текста. Подробнее написано, например, здесь: https://rus.stackexchange.com/help/editing.

Вы правы: это общее правило для всей сети Stack Exchange, изменить которое не представляется возможным. Его цель — избежать описанного выше, то есть мелких, незначительных правок.

В редких случаях, когда система не позволяет внести действительно нужную правку, к сообщению можно привлечь внимание модератора, воспользовавшись тревогой.

Comment: Благодарю за ваш ответ! Но вы не до конца ответили ... Модератор может делать правки сообщений длиной менее 6 символов или нет?

Comment: @AlexandrKazakov как можно видеть, я внес правку, а значит, у модераторов есть такая возможность :) Однако — заметьте — модераторы никак не могут повлиять на это ограничение у других пользователей.